# Merge 3D Objects In Realtime

Tags: c#, c++, 3d, xna, directx

I was wondering how people would approach the problem of merging two 3D objects?

The user can place shapes around the scene (cubes, cuboids, spheres, pyramids), and when he moves an object to intersect with another, I want the object to merge with the other object instead of going through it.

Here is a diagram to better explain:
[image]

I am thinking that maybe generate a point cloud for both models, that then removes points from the cuboid that intersect with the sphere, before finally recreating the model from the points?

All that point data would surely be a huge perf problem though? Not too sure how to recreate a model from point data either.

Comment: Constructive solid geometry and arbitrary surface tessellation are non-trivial exercises to say the least... what are you trying to accomplish?  Would something higher-level suffice (like Povray)?

Comment: Can you just group the objects together with some fixed relationship between them, so they move together from then on?  More information about the objectives of this question would be very helpful.

Comment: It's so a user can create a basic mesh out of simple shapes. From there the mesh can then be taken further with other modelling techniques. What more would you like to know? (note: I know that another program could be used, but I would rather have my own program so I can expand on it). Impearce that wouldn't be ideal as I want the objects to fluidly merge as the user drags the objects into one another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at the awesome [CSG site](http://evanw.github.com/csg.js/) by Evan Wallace.

That's live code, very clean and documented JavaScript (see [docs](http://evanw.github.com/csg.js/docs/)), with a liberal license .

Porting to C# or C++ should be an interesting task.